# Biber broken on Debian bullseye/sid texlive

Tags: biblatex, texlive, biber, debian

On Debian bullseye/sid, I upgraded my texlive install (version 2019.20191208-4 - testing) but biber (2.13-1) is broken:

Ex (see source files below):

```
> pdflatex foo.tex
```

compiles normally (and suggests to run biber) then

```
> biber foo
```

has output:

```
Unsuccessful stat on filename containing newline at /usr/share/perl5/XML/LibXML/Simple.pm line 232.
data source % biber.conf [2011/07/17 v0.1f biblatex-juradiss]
% Release Notes can be found in the README.txt


<map>
  <bibtex>
   <globalfield>
     decision        usera
     sign            userb
     officialvolume  userc
     officialpages   userd
     journalyear     usere
     decisionname    userf
   </globalfield>
  </bibtex>
</map>
 not found in .
```

This happens, for instance with this `foo.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bar.bib}
\begin{document}
Hello \cite{bla2014} World.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and `bar.bib`:

```
@book{bla2014,
   title =     {Bla bla},
   author =    {John Doe},
   publisher = {De Boeck},
   year =      {2014}
}
```

I tried to install other versions of biber but it is not really feasible due to incompatibility with `texlive-bibtex-extra` or other packages in Debian.

For some reason, the default `biber.conf` seems to be the BibLaTeX stylefiles for German law thesis:

```
kpsewhich biber.conf
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/biblatex-juradiss/biber.conf
```

so I also tried to create a `biber.conf` file in . by copying the xml file described in `http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/biblio/biber/documentation/biber.pdf` but it is for 2.14 and does not work either.

Any idea of what I can do?

Thanks for your help.

Lancelot

Comment: Surely this is something you should report to the Debian TeX live/Biber maintainers.

Comment: Posting here was a suggestion from a biber maintener but if there is a better place, I will ask there of course.

Comment: All I can say is that the `biber.conf` from `biblatex-juradiss` is completely outdated (not unlike the rest of `biblatex-juradiss`) and not compatible with a current Biber. I'm a bit surprised that `kpsewhich biber.conf` finds files in the `/doc` subtree of the TeX live tree.

Comment: OK thanks. Actually I searched, without success, for the proper biber.conf in v2.13 to copy it to . hoping that it could possibly allow to circumvent the problem.

Comment: On my vanilla TeX live (from TUG.org) on Ubuntu `kpsewhich biber.conf` does not find `doc/latex/biblatex-juradiss/biber.conf` even though it is installed. (It was my understanding that `kpsewhich` does not search the `doc` subtree by default). Contact the Debian TeX live maintainers and ask them if this is an intentional change. (This is not a Biber issue as such, so the Biber developer probably can't help you here: The Biber Debian maintainer would be more relevant, but I think this is a Debian TeX live issue).

Comment: I just sent a message to debian-tex-maint@lists.debian.org with a link to this url. Btw, it seems `doc/latex/biblatex-juradiss/biber.conf` is installed by `texlive-bibtex-extra` not by the `biber` package itself.

Comment: If kpsewhich finds a file in the doc hierarchy, then you have messed up something. Can you show the output of all TeX related variables in your environment, that is `set | grep -i tex` - my guess is that you have some misconfiguration.

Comment: And the output (lengthy) of `kpsewhich -debug=-1 biber.conf`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your useful comments! Indeed, the problem was due to an old dirty hack I forgot I made on environment variables. From older TeX installations, I did not use `TEXMFHOME` and used a custom `TEXINPUTS` that was not set properly and had `:/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist//:` as a substring.
I unset `TEXINPUTS`, moved my TeX stuff to `$MYDEVPATH/texmf` and set `TEXMFHOME=$MYDEVPATH/texmf`.

Now everything works fine!

Comment: Can you tell us more about that dirty hack, so other people are warned against it? In the current form the question and answer don't really help other people.

Comment: Nothing fancy but sure, I'll edit the post.